# Imprimir texto de retorno json no meio do código - JQuery/JavaScript/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho um gráfico que é criado conforme o ano, que é passado por AJAX e retorna um JSON contendo os valores pra criar o gráfico. Pois bem, eu envio o AJAX com o ano, retorno o JSON, porém... Dá erro, ele cria tudo errado, segue meu código.

Meu controlador onde retorno os dados e crio o JSON:

```
public function comparativo_json(){
    $html = '';
    $data = $this->relatoriosmodel->getComparativo($this->input->post('ano'));

    $html .= '[';
    foreach($data['mesesFuncionario'] as $func):
        $html .= "{";
            $html .= "name: '".$data['funcionarioDados'][$func['id']]->nome."',";
            unset($func['id']);
            $html .= "data: [ "; foreach($func as $f){ $html .= $f.','; } substr($f,-1); $html .= "]";
        $html .= "},";
    endforeach; 
    $html .= ']';

    echo json_encode($html);
}
```

Meu JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#ano').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/relatorio/comparativo_json',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {ano: $("#ano option:selected").val()},
            success: function(data){

                $('#containerHighCharts').highcharts({
                    title: {
                        text: 'Comparativo de Vendas',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Ano de Referência: '+$("#ano option:selected").val(),
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
                            'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Reais (R$)'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' (R$) Reais'
                    },
                    legend:{
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: data,
                });
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

O JSON que ele retorna, que por sinal está correto, conforme o padrão pedido pelo plugin:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Richard Feliciano',
        data: [ 0,0,0,0,1816,17100,2400,0,0,0,0,0,]
    },
    {
        name: 'Ewerton Melo',
        data: [ 0,0,0,0,0,12400,0,0,0,0,0,0,]
    },
]
```

Imagem contendo o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só preciso fazer com que o retorno `data` seja impresso corretamente.

Comment: O problema está especificamente na impressão do `series: data,`

Comment: A unica coisa que me ocorre é que esteja a esquecer de fazer o [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), porque de resto parece-me bem: __http://jsfiddle.net/yb3Nt/__ Teste assim: `series: JSON.parse(data),` Teste também `console.log(data);` ou `console.log(typeof data);` e comente aqui o que obtêm.

Comment: Fiz o `console.log(typeof data);` e ele retorna como `string`, logo abaixo fiz o parse `var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data)` e retornou erro: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n`

Comment: De fato deve ser a conversão para JSON dessa string

Comment: Ok, e o que obtêm se fizer `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: `[{name: 'Richard Feliciano',data: [ 0,0,0,0,1816,17100,2400,0,0,0,0,0,]},{name: 'Ewerton Melo',data: [ 0,0,0,0,0,12400,0,0,0,0,0,0,]},]`

Comment: Ele retorna o padrão do JSON certinho, mas como string. Tentei `JSON.parse(data)` ou `$.parseJSON(data)` e o erro é o mesmo apresentado no comentário acima...

Comment: E se parar pra analisar, eu dou json_encode() logo no retorno do valor.

Comment: Tentei também o `JSON.stringify(data)` que conforme consultei em alguns fóruns também serve para converter string em JSON, porém, ele mantém como string. Fiz direto só pra testar `console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(data));` mas mesmo assim continua como string.

Comment: Ou você cria um array/objeto e usa o json_encode() ou então cria uma string e não usa o encode. No caso da segunda opção (que é o que está a fazer), coloque aspas `"` à volta da chave, e valor que seja string, de cada objeto. E retire as virgulas a mais. Aí essa string vai ser aceite pelo JSON. Dê uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/n3ARn/

Comment: @Sergio, muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas as dicas passadas abaixo resolveram o problema. Muito obrigado mesmo pela disposição em ajudar. Um abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um problema aqui:

```
foreach($data['mesesFuncionario'] as $func):
    $html .= "{";
        $html .= "name: '".$data['funcionarioDados'][$func['id']]->nome."',";
        unset($func['id']);
        $html .= "data: [ "; foreach($func as $f){ $html .= $f.','; } substr($f,-1); $html .= "]";
    $html .= "},";
endforeach;
```

O formato da string json não pode ter uma vírgula no fim, ela só separa os objetos. Segue o exemplo que você deu:

```
[{name: 'Richard Feliciano',data: [ 0,0,0,0,1816,17100,2400,0,0,0,0,0,]},{name: 'Ewerton Melo',data: [ 0,0,0,0,0,12400,0,0,0,0,0,0,]},]
```

Ele deveria ser:

```
[{name: 'Richard Feliciano',data: [ 0,0,0,0,1816,17100,2400,0,0,0,0,0,]},{name: 'Ewerton Melo',data: [ 0,0,0,0,0,12400,0,0,0,0,0,0,]}]
```

Repare que removi a última vírgula. Não entendo de PHP, mas o que você precisa fazer é verificar para que ele não adicione a última vírgula.

Depois de corrigir isso é só usar JSON.parse(data); que irá funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: Talvez você ainda tenha problemas por não usar aspas dupla, mas confira isso... se der problema no parse, mude para aspas duplas na sua string JSON: [{name: "Richard Feliciano",data: [ 0,0,0,0,1816,17100,2400,0,0,0,0,0,]},{name: "Ewerton Melo",data: [ 0,0,0,0,0,12400,0,0,0,0,0,0,]}]

Comment: Muito obrigado era isso mesmo, usei a função do PHP `substr($html,0,-1)` para remover o último elemento da string, nos pontos onde encerrava com `,` e funcionou perfeitamente, retornou o gráfico.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha dado certo. Com strings JSON é muito importante manter o formato correto quando convertemos para um objeto em determinada linguagem. Você também pode tentar usar métodos padrão em PHP para formar strings JSON ao invés de escrever a string à mão, isso torna seu código menos suscetível a erros!